# error on showing gradle dependencies tree

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i am using android studio to create simple image slider project and i am using [this library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlide). but when i want to see dependencies tree i got 100 error. i have searched a lot bot does not see such even problem.
here is build gradle :

[image]

here is errors:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/dA7iE.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/gn1Sd.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/sGz7b.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/uCskg.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/8ahmX.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/afjzC.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/Miwe0.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/rkWnQ.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/jC8J4.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/dho7G.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/LVtoJ.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/ZSemS.png]

and i have installed support library repository:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

this is not an error you are running the application as `gradle androidDependencies` and it's showing you the used dependencies change it from the run menu and select `app`

[image]